# gang of four design patterns -- Objective C sample code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, gang-of-four

I'm curious if anyone knows of any downloadable Objective C sample code for the gang of four design patterns out there?  I am looking for working sample XCode projects and don't mind paying!

Incidentally, if you're looking for other languages, you could start [here for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns) or [here for various languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)

Comment: I do like this question, but I still think it's off topic since it simply asks for resources, and as such, I voted to close it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no Gang of Four but Apress has *Pro Objective-C Design Patterns for iOS* by Carlo Chung which has many of these patterns in it.  Other than that, I'm not sure of one place that has so many of these patterns represented in Objective C.

Comment: Yeah, but as best I can tell, the book doesn't come with working projects, which is how I learn.

Comment: Sure it does... http://www.apress.com/9781430233305/ click the "Source Code/Downloads" link

Comment: So it does; you've just made my day!

Answer (score 2):

The following link has covered some of the Design Patterns

1. Facade (One single interface above a complex hierarchy)
2. MVC(Most popular,nothing to say)
3. Decorator(View dependent models)
4. Composite(Complex hierarchy of views as well as Objects)
5. Adapter (Protocol Specific)
6. Observer(adding observer while property value changes)
   6.1. KVO (Key Value Observing Pattern,associated with Observer)
   6.2. Notification Style
7. Memento (Archiving the View's state and restoring on app reload)
8. Command (Most commonly known as Target-Action design pattern)

generally used to solve some issues found while developing Applications.... 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns

Answer (score 0):

there's not a book for specific code with design patters applied, but a couple of them have really useful examples *Clean Code* and *Clean Coder*